# Reading a unix command output with Perl

Tags: perl, tcl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I need to run a command with variables inside of the command. I need to capture the output and save it in either one line varible or an array, it doesn't matter. It's going to be pasted into a textbox in Tk anyways.

I've tried:

```
my @array = '$variable_with_command';
```

I can't really use:

```
my $variable = 'unixcommand $variableinside';
```

because of the variable inside, i've seen that as a suggestion other stackoverflow posts.

It works for:

```
my $readvariable = 'ls -a';
```

because there are no variables inside, unless there's a way to include variables and have  $readvariable catch the output? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code (this printed zero):

```
sub runBatch {
    my $directory = "/directpath/directoryuser/sasmodules/";
    my $command = 'sasq ' . $directory . $selectBatch; 
    my @batch = system($command);
    print "This is the output\n";
    print "-----------------------------------";
    print @batch; 
    print "-----------------------------------";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with variables in the command. It has to do with the [`system`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#system) command not doing what you think it does. To capture the output of an external command, you want to use backticks, the `qx()` operator, or [`readpipe`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#readpipe).

Comment: Thanks, however if it wasn't for the variables i would not have a problem. I believe using back quotes be it the right way or not, works for my issue. I am sure there are many solutions as Perl seems to have.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer in case it helps anyone based on qx comment.

```
sub runBatch { 
    my @batch = qx(sasq $director);
    print "This is the output\n";
    print "-----------------------------------\n";
    print @batch; 
    print "-----------------------------------\n";
}
```

This actually works really well--using back quotes: `

```
sub runBatch {
    my $directory = "/path/directory/sasmodules/" . $selectBatch;
    my $command = `sasq $directory`; 
    #my @batch = command
    print "This is the output\n";
    print "-----------------------------------\n";
    print $command; 
    print "-----------------------------------\n";
    print $selectBatch;
}
```